# Swift adjust fonts to height within a vertical stack

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, resize, stack

I got a CollectionViewCell with a stack and labels in it. I want to make the content fitting to the size of the cell when resizing. I already used:

```
label1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label2.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label3.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

...to scale the font to the width and height. But whenever I'm decreasing the height of my cell, only the first one of my three labels is being adjusted. The others move out of vision. Do I need to somehow adjust the stack? And is there a way to resize all labels together so the proportions don't get mixed up?

Comment: What is the `distribution` property of your stack view? If you want all of your labels to have the same height, you should set it to `.fillEqually`. Otherwise, you will need to set the compression resistance of each label individually to achieve the layout that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to create a view in your case. Create a uiview and inside it put your stack view. But working with stack view is difficult due t the fact they don't respond well with change to frame.